# Given a pom.xml how to get list of remote repository URL & checksums

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aether

Wouldn't mind some help with the *aether* API which starts with a given *pom.xml*
I would like to then figure out the transitive closure for the whole project and emit:

1. The remote repository URI for each artifact
2. The checksum for each artifact

Comment: Do you need a solution only using `aether API` or other approaches are fine? If only with `aether API` then please add it to the title.

Comment: Repositories are mostly read from the `settings.xml`. Are you only interested in repositories specified in the POM itself?

Comment: @marc I'm interested in any solution not aether specific but it does seem to be the leading tool to fetch this information.

Comment: Ideally it would use whatever repositories the user has specified in the pom or the settings file however I'm also open to providing the repository.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do with this information?

Comment: I recommend to take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/resolver/

Comment: I will be feeding this information into a separate tool.